# How to calculate/estimate number of shards in Redis

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, redis-cluster, amazon-elasticache

I am currently exploring to use `AWS Elasticache(Redis -> Version 6.0.5)` and have estimated around `250GB` of data to be stored in Redis. To achieve high availability and high scalability, I will be sharding and replicating data. In AWS we have the following limits

```
Maximum Nodes - 90 (can be increased to 500 upon AWS support request)
Maximum Replicas - 5 
Maximum Shards - 15
Maximum nodes(90) = No of shards + No of replicas
```

I will be storing product the following data in Redis

```
Key          ->      Value
product_id          product_json_string
```

Is there any specific way or method of calculating the number of shards that will be required for storing such data ? I tried searching it on [Redis docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Shards.html) but did not find any information for the same.

Any inputs here will be highly helpful. Thanks !!!

Comment: Depends on the node size you want to choose, your replication requirements and access patterns (i.e. uniform or are some keys very hot).

Comment: @Maurice I am using `cache.r5.12xlarge` instance type, having 5 replicas each as my application is read heavy. Some of the keys are very frequently accessed.